# Sequence diagram. Can actor be in OPT?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I want that my agent “Cittadino” entry in OPT only if he is logged.

Is it corret my diagram? Or actor must be outside OPT?

Thanks so much

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIpeZ.jpg

Comment: Doesn't that Windoze have a screen shot functionality?

Comment: It might not have access to the so or able to put the screen shot somewhere in the net. I have this kind of limitation in my current location ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct in terms of UML compliance for `opt` part.

Let me question the existence of the whole `opt` in the first place. As I understand you're showing some behaviour and to perform that behaviour the actor has to be (earlier) logged into the system. If yes, make that a constraint of a behaviour in which case you don't have to depict that in the diagram of the behaviour itself at all.

Also I have doubts about the `alt` part. If only internal processing (arrows 1.1.1. and 1.1.2.) depend on conditions, only they should be inside `opt`. Arrows 1.1. and 1.1.3. have stay outside of it. In general your arrows should not cross the borders of an expansion region unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks . Maybe photo isnt very good. This Is new photo: https://ibb.co/c7MAhd.  If user its logged, so he can entry in Personal area. In personal area he can press “new tiket” . If he using mobile terminal and gps is on , so he can create new tiket, else he is rederict again to personal area.

Comment: Pictures are clearer indeed. Also I recommend you add the task description to the question since they make the requirements clearer. My point remains valid, since this is a behaviour that is enabled only for a logged user, it should be a constraint on a behaviour level and not necessarily shown in the diagram. But since this is probably some exercise and you might be required to put that in the picture, this part is OK. As for the rest of my answer - if the alternative path contains both 1.1.2. and 1.1.3. you should extend the alt expansion region to include fully 1.1.3 as well.